# How do I specify directory for screenschots? Lubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: directory, screenshot

The screenshots I take using PrtSc button are stored in my /home directory. Is it possible to specify another directory? I do not get an option to specify where I would like my screenshot to be saved using this method.
Cheers
David